# Why does Shizuku's room become larger in "Whisper of the Heart"?

Tags: whisper-of-the-heart

At some point during "Whisper of the Heart", Shizuku falls asleep at her desk while working on her story. She has a fantastic dream involving Baron and, when she wakes up, her room is larger. While her bed was right next to the desk before, there's now space for a whole window between them.

I believe this represents her personal space becoming larger with her sister moving out, but I'm not sure if there is something else I missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed this too. The reason is that the bunker bed used to be in the middle of Shizuku and her sister’s space (you can see it around 15:20 of the movie). After her sister moved out, the family must have moved the bed so Shizuku could have more space.